# Игра на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, разработка-игр, dos

Задали в университете написать игру на языке ассемблер 8086, работающую в DOSBox.72. Выбрал для себя простейший раннер. нарисовал рисунок, с остальным не могу разобраться, препод помогать не хочет. Помогите, кто чем может, пожалуйста.
Нужно движение шара вперёд и перепрыгивание прямоугольников. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.(желательно ещё счетчик завести, но с этим попробую сам справится)
Рисунок:

```
code segment
assume cs:code, ds:data
jumps
begin:
mov ax, data
mov ds,ax
mov ah,0Fh
int 10h
push ax
mov ax, 0013h
int 10h
;==========


mov ax, data
mov ds,ax
push ds



mov Rectangle_X1, 0
mov Rectangle_Y1, 0
mov Rectangle_X2, 320
mov Rectangle_Y2, 200
mov Rectangle_Color, 15
call Rectangle

mov Rectangle_X1, 0
mov Rectangle_Y1, 151
mov Rectangle_X2, 320
mov Rectangle_Y2, 165
mov Rectangle_Color, 2
call Rectangle

mov Rectangle_X1, 45
mov Rectangle_Y1, 140
mov Rectangle_X2, 55
mov Rectangle_Y2, 151
mov Rectangle_Color, 6
call Rectangle

mov FillCircle_X, 25
mov FillCircle_Y , 140
mov FillCircle_R, 10
mov FillCircle_Color,55
call FillCircle




mov ah,02h
mov bh, 0
mov dh, 23
mov dl, 22
int 10h


mov dx, offset fio
mov ah,9h
int 21h

;==========
mov ax,0
int 16h
pop ax
mov ah,0
int 10h
mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
;-------------------------------------------------------
FillCircle proc
push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx
push di
push si
push es
push FillCircle_R   

mov ax,0A000h           ;установка es
mov es,ax               ;на видеопамять

mov ax,FillCircle_R     ;R*R
mul ax                  ;
mov dx,ax               ;

push dx                 ;расчет di
inc FillCircle_R        ;
mov ax,320              ;
mov bx,FillCircle_Y     ;
sub bx,FillCircle_R     ;
mul bx                  ;
mov cx,FillCircle_X     ;
sub cx,FillCircle_R     ;
add ax,cx               ;
mov di,ax               ;
pop dx                  ;

FillCircle_Draw:

push dx
mov ax,cx               ;x
sub ax,FillCircle_X     ;x-Xc
mul ax                  ;(x-Xc)^2
mov si,ax
mov ax,bx               ;y
sub ax,FillCircle_Y     ;y-Yc
mul ax                  ;(y-Yc)^2
add ax,si               ;(x-Xc)^2 + (y-Yc)^2
pop dx

cmp ax,dx   ;ax > R*R ?
ja  FillCircle_Not_Draw ;если да

mov ah,FillCircle_Color
mov es:[di],byte ptr ah ;вывод точки

FillCircle_Not_Draw:
inc di
inc cx


mov ax,FillCircle_X
add ax,FillCircle_R
cmp cx,ax               ;ограничение по Х
jne FillCircle_Draw


mov cx,FillCircle_X
sub cx,FillCircle_R

add di,320
sub di,FillCircle_R
sub di,FillCircle_R
inc bx

mov ax,FillCircle_Y
add ax,FillCircle_R
cmp bx,ax               ;ограничение по Y
jl  FillCircle_Draw

pop FillCircle_R
pop es
pop si
pop di
pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
ret
FillCircle endp
Rectangle proc
push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx
mov ah,0ch
mov bx,0
mov al,Rectangle_Color
mov cx,Rectangle_X1
mov dx,Rectangle_Y1
Rectangle_Label:
int 10h
inc cx
cmp cx, Rectangle_X2
jne Rectangle_Label
mov cx,Rectangle_X1
inc dx
cmp dx,Rectangle_Y2
jne Rectangle_Label
pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
ret
Rectangle endp
code ends
data segment 
FillCircle_X dw 0 
FillCircle_Y dw 0 
FillCircle_R dw 0 
FillCircle_Color db 0 
Rectangle_X1 dw 0
Rectangle_Y1 dw 0
Rectangle_X2 dw 0
Rectangle_Y2 dw 0
Rectangle_Color db 0
fio db 'Circle Running$'
data ends
end begin
```

Немного пошел прогресс:

```
code segment
assume cs:code, ds:data
jumps

begin:
mov ah,0Fh
int 10h
push ax
mov ax, 0013h
int 10h

mov ax, data
mov ds,ax
push ds
mov ax,351ch
int 21h
mov word ptr OldInt1ch,bx
mov word ptr OldInt1ch+2,es
mov ax,251ch
mov dx,seg MyInt1ch
mov ds,dx
mov dx,offset MyInt1ch
int 21h
pop ds

random_food:
mov find_food,0
call DeleteFood
mov rmin,12
mov rmax,308
call WIRandom
mov X_Food,ax
mov rmin,12
mov rmax,188
call WIRandom
mov Y_Food,ax
call DrawFood
call DrawBorder

met:
cmp find_food,1
je random_food
cmp find_border,1
je key_esc
cmp vektor,0
je met_0
cmp vektor,1
je met_0
cmp vektor,2
je met_1
cmp vektor,3
je met_1
jmp met

met_0:
mov ax,0
int 16h
cmp ah,11h
je key_up
cmp ah,1Fh
je key_down
cmp ah,01h
je key_esc
jmp met

met_1:
mov ax,0
int 16h
cmp ah,20h
je key_right
cmp ah,1Eh
je key_left
cmp ah,01h
je key_esc
jmp met

key_esc:
mov ax,251ch
mov dx,word ptr OldInt1ch
mov bx,word ptr OldInt1ch+2
mov ds,bx
int 21h
mov ax,4c00h
int 21h

key_right:
mov vektor,0
jmp met
key_left:
mov vektor,1
jmp met
key_up:
mov vektor,2
jmp met
key_down:
mov vektor,3
jmp met

vektor_right:
mov di, arX[0]
push di
mov ah,0dh
add di,4
mov cx, si
mov dx, di
mov bh,15
int 10h
pop di
cmp al,5
je findfood
;cmp al,6
;je gameover
mov es,arX[0]
mov cx,arY[0]
add arX[0],6
mov di,ex1
mov si,ex2
mov ex3,di
mov ex4,si
v_r:
mov di,ex1
mov si,ex2
mov bx,arX[si]
mov arX[di],bx
mov bx,arY[si]
mov arY[di],bx
sub ex1,2
sub ex2,2
cmp ex1,2
jne v_r
mov arX[2],es
mov arY[2],cx
mov di,ex3
mov si,ex4
mov ex1,di
mov ex2,si
jmp return





vektor_left:
mov di, arX[0]
push di
mov ah,0dh
sub di,4
mov cx, si
mov dx, di     
mov bh,15
int 10h
pop di
cmp al,5
je findfood
;cmp al,6
;je gameover
mov es,arX[0]
mov cx,arY[0]
sub arX[0],6
mov di,ex1
mov si,ex2
mov ex3,di
mov ex4,si
v_l:
mov di,ex1
mov si,ex2
mov bx,arX[si]
mov arX[di],bx
mov bx,arY[si]
mov arY[di],bx
sub ex1,2
sub ex2,2
cmp ex1,2
jne v_r
mov arX[2],es
mov arY[2],cx
mov di,ex3
mov si,ex4
mov ex1,di
mov ex2,si
jmp return

vektor_up:
mov di, arY[0]
push si
mov ah,0dh
sub si,4
mov cx, si
mov dx, di
mov bh,15
int 10h
pop si
cmp al,5
je findfood
;cmp al,6
;je gameover
mov es,arX[0]
mov cx,arY[0]
sub arY[0],6
mov di,ex1
mov si,ex2
mov ex3,di
mov ex4,si
v_u:
mov di,ex1
mov si,ex2
mov bx,arX[si]
mov arX[di],bx
mov bx,arY[si]
mov arY[di],bx
sub ex1,2
sub ex2,2
cmp ex1,2
jne v_r
mov arX[2],es
mov arY[2],cx
mov di,ex3
mov si,ex4
mov ex1,di
mov ex2,si
jmp return

vektor_down:
mov si, arY[0]
push si
mov ah,0dh
add si,4
mov cx, si
mov dx, di
mov bh,15
int 10h
pop si
cmp al,5
je findfood
;cmp al,6
;je gameover
mov es,arX[0]
mov cx,arY[0]
add arY[0],6
mov di,ex1
mov si,ex2
mov ex3,di
mov ex4,si
v_d:
mov di,ex1
mov si,ex2
mov bx,arX[si]
mov arX[di],bx
mov bx,arY[si]
mov arY[di],bx
sub ex1,2
sub ex2,2
cmp ex1,2
jne v_r
mov arX[2],es
mov arY[2],cx
mov di,ex3
mov si,ex4
mov ex1,di
mov ex2,si
jmp return

findfood:
mov find_food,1
jmp return

gameover:
mov find_border,1
mov ah,02h
mov bh,0
mov dh,12
mov dl,15
int 10h
mov dx, offset gameover1
mov ah,9h
int 21h
jmp return

MyInt1ch proc
push si
push di
mov di,X_Snake
mov si,Y_Snake
call DeleteSnake
cmp vektor,0
je vektor_right
cmp vektor,1
je vektor_left
cmp vektor,2
je vektor_up
cmp vektor,3
je vektor_down
return:
call DrawSnake
mov X_Snake,di
mov Y_Snake,si
pop di
pop si
iret
MyInt1ch endp


DeleteSnake proc
mov sum,0
ret1:
mov bx, sum
mov di, arX[bx]
mov si, arY[bx]
mov FillCircle_X, di
mov FillCircle_Y , si
mov FillCircle_R, 5
mov FillCircle_Color,55
call FillCircle
add sum,2
mov cx,sum
cmp ex1,cx
jne ret1
ret
DeleteSnake endp

DrawSnake proc
mov sum,0
ret2:
mov bx, sum
mov di, arX[bx]
mov si, arY[bx]
mov FillCircle_X, di
mov FillCircle_Y , si
mov FillCircle_R, 5
mov FillCircle_Color,55
call FillCircle
add sum,2
mov cx,sum
cmp ex1,cx
jne ret2
ret
DrawSnake endp

DeleteFood proc
mov bx, X_Food
mov cx, Y_Food
mov FillCircle_X, bx
mov FillCircle_Y , cx
mov FillCircle_R, 2
mov FillCircle_Color,0
call FillCircle
ret
DeleteFood endp

DrawFood proc
mov bx, X_Food
mov cx, Y_Food
mov FillCircle_X, bx
mov FillCircle_Y , cx
mov FillCircle_R, 2
mov FillCircle_Color,5
call FillCircle
ret
DrawFood endp

DrawBorder proc

mov Rectangle_X1, 0
mov Rectangle_Y1, 0
mov Rectangle_X2, 320
mov Rectangle_Y2, 200
mov Rectangle_Color, 15
call Rectangle
mov Rectangle_X1, 0
mov Rectangle_Y1, 151
mov Rectangle_X2, 320
mov Rectangle_Y2, 165
mov Rectangle_Color, 2
call Rectangle
mov Rectangle_X1, 45
mov Rectangle_Y1, 140
mov Rectangle_X2, 55
mov Rectangle_Y2, 151
mov Rectangle_Color, 6
call Rectangle
ret
DrawBorder endp

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

WRandom proc    
push dx 
push cx
mov ax,[random_seed]
or ax,ax
jnz @@
mov ah,2ch
int 21h
mov al,dl
mov ah,dh
mov dl,cl
mov dh,ch
xor ax,dx
mov [random_seed],ax
@@:
xor dx,dx
mov cx,12777
div cx
mov cx,ax
mov ax,16807
mul dx
mov dx,cx
mov cx,ax
mov ax,2836
mul dx
sub cx,ax
xor dx,dx
mov ax,cx
mov [random_seed],cx
mov cx,10000
div cx
mov ax,dx
pop cx 
pop dx
ret
endp
WIRandom proc
push dx 
push cx
mov  cx,[rmax]
sub  cx,[rmin]
inc  cx
call WRandom
xor dx,dx
div cx
mov ax,dx
add ax,[rmin]
pop cx 
pop dx
ret
WIRandom  endp
WRandomInit proc    
push ax
push dx
mov ah,2ch
int 21h
mov al,dl
mov ah,dh
mov dl,cl
mov dh,ch
xor ax,dx
mov [random_seed],ax
pop dx 
pop ax
ret
WRandomInit endp
FillCircle proc
push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx
push di
push si
push es
push FillCircle_R   
mov ax,0A000h           
mov es,ax               
mov ax,FillCircle_R     
mul ax              
mov dx,ax               
push dx                 
inc FillCircle_R        
mov ax,320              
mov bx,FillCircle_Y     
sub bx,FillCircle_R     
mul bx                  
mov cx,FillCircle_X     
sub cx,FillCircle_R     
add ax,cx               
mov di,ax               
pop dx                  
FillCircle_Draw:
push dx
mov ax,cx               
sub ax,FillCircle_X     
mul ax                  
mov si,ax
mov ax,bx               
sub ax,FillCircle_Y     
mul ax                  
add ax,si               
pop dx
cmp ax,dx   
ja  FillCircle_Not_Draw 
mov ah,FillCircle_Color
mov es:[di],byte ptr ah 
FillCircle_Not_Draw:
inc di
inc cx  
mov ax,FillCircle_X
add ax,FillCircle_R
cmp cx,ax               
jne FillCircle_Draw
mov cx,FillCircle_X
sub cx,FillCircle_R
add di,320
sub di,FillCircle_R
sub di,FillCircle_R
inc bx
mov ax,FillCircle_Y
add ax,FillCircle_R
cmp bx,ax               
jl  FillCircle_Draw
pop FillCircle_R
pop es
pop si
pop di
pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
ret
FillCircle endp
Rectangle proc
push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx
mov ah,0ch
mov bx,0
mov al,Rectangle_Color
mov cx,Rectangle_X1
mov dx,Rectangle_Y1
Rectangle_Label:
int 10h
inc cx
cmp cx, Rectangle_X2
jne Rectangle_Label
mov cx,Rectangle_X1
inc dx
cmp dx,Rectangle_Y2
jne Rectangle_Label
pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
ret
Rectangle endp

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

code ends
data segment
OldInt1ch dd 00
Rectangle_X1 dw 0
Rectangle_Y1 dw 0
Rectangle_X2 dw 0
Rectangle_Y2 dw 0
Rectangle_Color db 0
FillCircle_X dw 0
FillCircle_Y dw 0
FillCircle_R dw 0
FillCircle_Color db 0
rmin dw 0
rmax dw 0
random_seed dw 0 
X_Snake dw 160
Y_Snake dw 100
X_Food dw 0
Y_Food dw 0
vektor db 0
find_border db 0
find_food db 0
array dw 20 dup(0)
gameover1 db 'GAME OVER',13,10,'$'
arX dw 160,154,148,142,136,130,130,130
arY dw 100,100,100,100,100,100,106,112
sum dw 0
ex1 dw 14
ex2 dw 12
ex3 dw 0
ex4 dw 0
temp dw 0
data ends
end begin
```

Comment: Нарисуйте декартовую систему координат, например. Выберите точку отсчёта. Тогда движение вперёд - наращивание x. Прыжок - нарастить y и вернуть назад.

Comment: Больше конкретики.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, в координатах немного разбираюсь. Нужен именно сам код на прыжки. Конкретно есть рисунок: 2 прямоугольника и круг, так вот этот круг должен совершать прыжки при нажатии клавиши W, после "перепрыгивания" первого прямоугольника, должны появляться следующие прямоугольники и т.д. При этом кол-во прыжков должно считаться. Надеюсь, что хоть немного добавил конкретики. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Прыжок состоит из: вверх `inc your_obj_y;`  вниз `dec your_obj_y;`

Comment: не совсем понимаю тебя, я немного с помощью своего товарища реализовал движение(он пишет змейку и помог мне) если не трудно, посмотри правленый вопрос, и подскажи где нужно исправить. Бужу очень признателен.